# Async code misleading in aspnet identity

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I need to implement a custom Storage provider for aspnetidentity.
I had a good look round and i found quite a few.However they seem all wrong to me.

My understing is that if you have a method that ends with "async" than it should by asynchronous.

See example taken from somebody's code and this is scattered all over the place.

I **find below very misleading since it's not Async at all from what I can see**:

```
    public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
    {
        TUser result = userTable.GetUserById(userId) as TUser;  //this is not async 
        if (result != null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<TUser>(result);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<TUser>(null);
    }
```

**should this be coded like this?:**

```
     public async Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
        {

            TUser result = userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId) as TUser;
            if (result != null)
            {
                return await Task.FromResult<TUser>(result);
            }

            return await Task.FromResult<TUser>(null);
        }

    Questions?
```

1. Is it correct to do "Task.FromResult"? What I mean is does "Task.FromResult actually turns into synchronous? what should it be?
2. What is the correct way to code the above? what about configureAwait(false)
       should async be "All the way down including datalayer to avoid deadlocking"

any sample code /snippet would be appreciated

many thanks for any feedback

Comment: the first one only wraps the synchronous call to `GetUserById` to *fake* it as async (at least you can use it with await now) - the second one is completely useless as you could just use `userTable.GetUserByIdAsync` - you basically just unpack and repack it

Comment: Where does `GetUserByIdAsync` come from? Does it actually exist? If it does, just return its result as Task<User>.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added GetUserByIdAsync as an example myself of what I think should be

Comment: "if you have a method that ends with "async" than it should by asynchronous". I'd phrase it as it *may* be asynchronous. There can be plenty of reasons why a *potentially* asynchronous method may act synchronously (although there will *usually* be at least one potential path where it will be asynchronous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is not misleading. ASP.NET Identity framework has been designed to provide an asynchronous interface by returning a `Task` and indicating this by adding the `Async` suffix to the method name:

```
Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
```

However, the underlying provider may not have asynchronous methods. In that case you cannot create an asynchronous implementation but you still have to implement the interface and to do that will have use `Task.FromResult` exactly as it is done in your first code snippet.

**Implementing an asynchronous method using synchronous code**

```
public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
{
    TUser result = userTable.GetUserById(userId) as TUser;
    return Task.FromResult<TUser>(result);
}
```

If your underlying provider supports asynchronous methods you should use async and await.

**Implementing an asynchronous method using asynchronous code**

```
public async Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
{
    TUser result = (await userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId)) as TUser;
    return result;
}
```

Note that `Task.FromResult` is not used. `Task.FromResult` is only needed when you have a `TResult` created by synchronous code and you have to convert it to `Task<TResult>` required by asynchronous code.

Sometimes your underlying provider can return the desired `Task<TUser>` without any further work. In that case you can remove the async and await and still provide an asynchronous implementation. This can result in slightly more efficient code:

```
public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
{
    Task<TUser> result = userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer but to me is still misleading and contractiding what they are preaching.If you have an "async" method that you should return an async implementation.Microsoft in their interfaces have been inconsistent as they are declaring method with "Async" but then when implementing you have to be syncronus. Now Could you clarify for me this please. in c# we only have FirstDefault ,ToList etc.. when you implement those do you make your code syncronous? Is my assumption correct?I hate EF but they do have FirstAndDefaultAsync etc...

Comment: @developer9969: There is nothing misleading in creating an interface that supports asynchronous operations by letting methods return `Task<T>`. If you want to implement this interface it is up to your to do it asynchronously. If you are using EF you should use `FirstOrDefatultAsync` however if you are using some other data access mechanism that does not support asynchronous operations you will have to create a synchronous implementation. If the road is safe for driving at 100 mph it is OK to set the speed limit at 100 mph and then decide to drive in a car that only can go as fast as 50 mph.

Comment: Point taken however in their interface they do " public Task CreateAsync(T user) should it not be " public Task<T> CreateAsync(T user)" so that you can do async all the way? I am not using EF I am using raw ado.net which is the fastest and i have no overloads for firstDefaultAsync ,toListAsync etc... pity.  Last question when you do a "FirstOrDefault" that is syncronous no?thanks. Just trying to understand   async/await books do not mention these things

Comment: @developer9969: `Task CreateAsync(T user)` is async "all the way". A non-async version of that method would be `void Create(T user)` which seems like the right signature. `void Something()` becomes `Task SomethingAsync()` and `T Something()` becomes `Task<T> SomethingAsync()` when you design asynchronous interface using the usual naming conventions. `FirstOrDefault()` returns `T` and is synchronous. EF's `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` returns `Task<T>` which makes it asynchronous. The calling thread is free to do other work while the database operation is in progress on the server and network.

Answer (score 0):

The initial code is definitely not asynchronous. It looks like it was put that way to cope with an API design.

However the proposed change doesn't look async to me either. `Task.FromResult` just creates a completed task with a result, doesn't make anything asynchronous or executes any kind of awaitable code so you should not await on it.

In your case, assuming `GetUserByIdAsync` returns a `Task<TUser>`, and assuming the whole purpose of this code (as it seems) is to always return a completed task (never faulted or cancelled), this could be rewritten as:

```
public async Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
{
   var tResult = userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);
   TUser result = null;
   try
   {
     result = await tResult;
   } 
   except
   {
     // Bad idea, but here goes to your first snippet
   }
   return Task.FromResult<TUser>(result);
}
```

**Note**: this is a bad idea as @PanagiotisKanavos commented, it's hiding a possibly faulted state and you won't ever know if your `null` result came the user not being found, or if there was an error condition: I'd avoid it.

If a faulted/cancelled state is valid, this could simply be:

```
public Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
{
   return userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId);
}
```

Comment: Actually, both these snippets are superfluous. The `try/finally`is pointless - it the method fails, the exception will be propagated. If it doesn't you unwrap the result to rewrap tin in a Task. You also *don't* need to use `async/await` when you only call asynchronous methods - just return the Task<User> as is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's right, I was editing the second snipped. The try/finally is there so that a faulted task will return as completed (which seems to be what the first snippet in the OP question is doing), and not as faulted

Comment: No it won't and it shouldn't. The exception will be propagated anyway. As for "hiding" the exception, it's a very bad idea. This would now force callers to deal with ambiguous null values. Not to mention, that the failure reason will be lost.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos woops, you are right, I've edited. I'll add a note on how that's a bad idea too (which I agree it is)

Comment: Hi,guys,thanks for your reply.I am trying to read the docs on async/await again because i am getting confused.In a nutshell how would you make the dal method totally async?btw GetUserByIdAsync is fictitious .I added myself to propose as a solution

Comment: @developer9969 as I mentioned in a comment, you *don't* make a method asynchronous by using `async/await`. You do this by using methods that *are* asynchronous already, eg the ExecuteScalarAsync method of a command instead of ExecuteScalar. Or Stream.WriteAsync instead of Stream.Write

Comment: @developer9969 you'd need an async method that accesses your data... on EF it could be `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, or in ado.net, `ExecuteScalarAsync`, or whatnot. Marking a method with async doesn't make it asynchronous: the operations inside it must be asynchronous (and be `await`ed). I was assuming `GetUserByIdAsync` actually existed, since you mentioned it.

Comment: @Jcl that is exactly my point .I have looked a many custom implementation of asp.net identity and all of them are wrong for the exact reason you are mentioning.But when I saw that all of them were wrong I started questioning myself.

Comment: what does task.FromResult do then? if this makes syncronous what makes asynchronus

Comment: @developer9969 `Task.FromResult` "fakes" a task completion with a result, but it does not execute any code. It's just mockery for other code that handles tasks. It's "to put it easily" as if you had created a `Task` with this action: `return result;` which has already finished.

Comment: @Jcl thanks ok so when implementing an async/await in your dal what should the response look like then

Answer (score 0):

An `async` method is a way for the compiler to build something that will return a **promise** our **future**. In the case of the .NET Framework and C#, that is a `Task`.

The `await` instruction takes any **awaitable** and `Task` just happens to be one. It doesn't know or care if the method/operations being invoked is really asynchronous or not.

`Task.FromResult<T>` returns a completed task and if you use it in an `await` instruction inside an `async` method it will be considered to have been completed synchronously and execution will continue.

So, using `async` and `await` with just calls to `Task.FromResult<T>` ends up just being a waste of CPU cycles and memory by the compiler generating code that will waste more CPU cycles and memory at run time.

Because an `async` method always returns a `Task` a decision was made to make it implicit to improve readability and give it some kind of **sync** feeling. The compile will wrap the return value in a `Task`. That's why you can't return `Task.FromResult<TUser>(result)` or `Task.FromResult<TUser>(null)` directly and are awaiting it to get the value.

So, the `async` equivalent of your synchronous code would be:

```
 public async Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
 {
    var result = await userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId) as TUser;
    if (result != null)
    {
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Or:

```
 public async Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(int userId)
 {
    return await userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId) as TUser;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.On a practical level how would you refactor the snippet above?I have read lots of docs and advise but I still do not know how to code it correctly

Comment: Do you have a `userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId)` method? Or just a `userTable.GetUserById(userId)` method?

Comment: I have a userTable.GetUserByIdAsync(userId).Also what happens when you do FirstOrDefault? since I am using pure ado.net i do not think there is a firstOrDefaulAsync. Does firstOrDefault makes async pointeless if so how are you supposed to overcome it?

Comment: What do you mean by "using pure ado.net"? Is it using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`?

Comment: First I apprecciate your time .yes i am using raw ado.net code no shit orm just sqlconnection and sql command etc...but I think we are going off course here.my question and post are very simple how would you refactor my simple code snippet to make sure is proper asyncronous simple!